# Setting Up SSL On A MAMP Server (Mac)

Tags: https, http, mac, mamp

I'm currently trying to set up SSL (create a secure website) using MAMP 6.6 on a Mac that's running Monterey 12.4. I have been able to create all of the necessary files (including the server root certificate), but seem to be having trouble when trying to implement them.

Listed below are the files I've created:

- `local-ca.key`
- `local-ca.pem`
- `local-ca.srl`
- `server.crt`
- `server.crt`
- `server.csr`
- `server.key`
- `v3.ext`

I've looked at a bunch of blogs explaining how to set up SSL, but have had no luck with any of the files I've created. I have already set my IP address so it routes through the domain name that I've bought (through GoDaddy). This wouldn't have anything to do with me not being able to set up a secure website, would it?

I've fiddled with the `httpd.conf` file and the `httpd-ssl.conf` file via the information given on the blogs and videos I referenced, but no luck. If anyone has any advice I'd appreciate it.

Comment: When you say you "created" the files, that means that you obtained them from a certificate authority, right?  The only one of those that I would expect you to create yourself would be the certificate request (`.csr`).

Comment: There are countless videos and blogs online that teach how to write your own SSL certificate and how to implement them. I've had no trouble creating the SSL certificate, but for whatever reason have trouble getting it to work on my MAMP server. I've been getting all sorts of error messages. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you're not getting it to work the cause is usually that it's not created correctly. Can you add more to your question about exactly how you created it